# How to display value in text box according to the value which is selected in the drop down box?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

How to display value in text box according to the value which is selected in the drop down box? All value fetching from mysql db only.if I am selecting devicename from dorpdown list then text box will display device imei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please put some code which you tried.
Getting data from database requires JDBC code for that tell what is your table structure and what columns it is having.
Anyways For changing the value on dropdown selection, can be achieved by simple JavaScript.On change event of dropdown can be used to call the js function which will change the value of textbox.

```
    <script>
function doChange() 
{
    var val = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("txtName");
    e.value = val;
}
</script>
<form>
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="doChange()">
<option value="IMEINumber1">Samsung</option>
<option value="IMEINumber2">Nokia</option>
<option value="IMEINumber3">Motorola</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" value="defualt" >
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? coz I think this would put "IMEINumber1" in the text box. Whereas, the OP would more likely expect the value "Samsung".

Comment: I tested the code, I am putting IMEINumber1 value in textbox when u select Samsung. Likewise what you want as value you have to mention in value part, whereas what you want to display should come in place of Samsung.

Comment: <form>
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="doChange()">
<option value="<%=content[1]%>"><%=content[0]%></option>
</select>

Comment: <form>
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="doChange()">
<option value="<%=content[1]%>"><%=content[0]%></option>
</select> in this content[1] is imei no and content[1] is devices name .Now it is displaying equivalent imei no for that device.But when i clicking submit button it passing imei number in the request.getparameter("mydropdown"); Actually i need to pass device name in the servlet.

Comment: please put your full code,that will be easy to understand